# RequestDispatcher.forward() vs HttpServletResponse.sendRedirect()

Tags: jsp, redirect, servlets, forward

What is the conceptual difference between `forward()` and `sendRedirect()`?

Answer (score 116, accepted):

> ### requestDispatcher - forward() method
>
> 1. When we use the `forward` method, the request is transferred to another resource within the same server for further processing.
> 2. In the case of `forward`, the web container handles all processing internally and the client or browser is not involved.
> 3. When `forward` is called on the `requestDispatcher`object, we pass the request and response objects, so our old request object is present on the new resource which is going to process our request.
> 4. Visually, we are not able to see the forwarded address, it is transparent.
> 5. Using the `forward()` method is faster than `sendRedirect`.
> 6. When we redirect using forward, and we want to use the same data in a new resource, we can use `request.setAttribute()` as we have a request object available.
>
> ### SendRedirect
>
> 1. In case of `sendRedirect`, the request is transferred to another resource, to a different domain, or to a 
>      different server for further processing.
> 2. When you use `sendRedirect`, the container transfers the request to the client or browser, so the URL given inside the `sendRedirect` method is visible as a new request to the client.
> 3. In case of `sendRedirect` call, the old request and response objects are lost because it’s treated as new request by the browser.
> 4. In the address bar, we are able to see the new redirected address. It’s not transparent.
> 5. `sendRedirect` is slower because one extra round trip is required, because a completely new request is created and the old request object is lost. Two browser request are required.
> 6. But in `sendRedirect`, if we want to use the same data for a new resource we have to store the data in session or pass along with the URL.
>
> ### Which one is good?
>
> Its depends upon the scenario for which method is more useful.
>
> If you want control is transfer to new server or context, and it is treated as completely new task, then we go for `sendRedirect`.
>   Generally, a forward should be used if the operation can be safely repeated upon a browser reload of the web page and will not affect the result.

[Source](http://javarevisited.blogspot.in/2011/09/sendredirect-forward-jsp-servlet.html)

Answer (score 177):

In the web development world, the term "redirect" is  the act of sending the client an empty HTTP response with just a `Location` header containing the new URL to which the client has to send a brand new GET request. So basically:

- Client sends a HTTP request to `some.jsp`.
- Server sends a HTTP response back with `Location: other.jsp` header
- Client sends a HTTP request to `other.jsp` (this get reflected in browser address bar!)
- Server sends a HTTP response back with content of `other.jsp`.

You can track it with the web browser's builtin/addon developer toolset. Press F12 in Chrome/IE9/Firebug and check the "Network" section to see it.

Exactly the above is achieved by `sendRedirect("other.jsp")`. The `RequestDispatcher#forward()` doesn't send a redirect. Instead, it uses the content of the target page as HTTP response.

- Client sends a HTTP request to `some.jsp`.
- Server sends a HTTP response back with content of `other.jsp`.

However, as the original HTTP request was to `some.jsp`, the URL in browser address bar remains unchanged. Also, any request attributes set in the controller behind `some.jsp` will be available in `other.jsp`. This does not happen during a redirect because you're basically forcing the client to create a **new** HTTP request on `other.jsp`, hereby throwing away the original request on `some.jsp` including all of its attribtues.

---

The `RequestDispatcher` is extremely useful in the MVC paradigm and/or when you want to hide JSP's from direct access. You can put JSP's in the `/WEB-INF` folder and use a `Servlet` which controls, preprocesses and postprocesses the requests. The JSPs in the `/WEB-INF` folder are not directly accessible by URL, but the `Servlet` can access them using `RequestDispatcher#forward()`.

You can for example have a JSP file in `/WEB-INF/login.jsp` and a `LoginServlet` which is mapped on an `url-pattern` of `/login`. When you invoke `http://example.com/context/login`, then the servlet's `doGet()` will be invoked. You can do any *pre*processing stuff in there and finally **forward** the request like:

```
request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/login.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

When you submit a form, you normally want to use `POST`:

```html
<form action="login" method="post">
```

This way the servlet's `doPost()` will be invoked and you can do any *post*processing stuff in there (e.g. validation, business logic, login the user, etc).

If there are any errors, then you normally want to **forward** the request back to the same page and display the errors there next to the input fields and so on. You can use the `RequestDispatcher` for this.

If a `POST` is successful, you normally want to **redirect** the request, so that the request won't be resubmitted when the user refreshes the request (e.g. pressing F5 or navigating back in history).

```
User user = userDAO.find(username, password);
if (user != null) {
    request.getSession().setAttribute("user", user); // Login user.
    response.sendRedirect("home"); // Redirects to http://example.com/context/home after succesful login.
} else {
    request.setAttribute("error", "Unknown login, please try again."); // Set error.
    request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/login.jsp").forward(request, response); // Forward to same page so that you can display error.
}
```

A **redirect** thus instructs the client to fire a new `GET` request on the given URL. Refreshing the request would then only refresh the redirected request and not the initial request. This will avoid "double submits" and confusion and bad user experiences. This is also called the [`POST-Redirect-GET` pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get).

#### See also:

- [How do servlets work? Instantiation, sessions, shared variables and multithreading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3106452/how-do-servlets-work-instantiation-sessions-shared-variables-and-multithreadi)
- [doGet and doPost in Servlets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2349633/doget-and-dopost-in-servlets)
- [How perform validation and display error message in same form in JSP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6464931/how-perform-validation-and-display-error-message-in-same-form-in-jsp)
- [HttpServletResponse sendRedirect permanent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9034149/httpservletresponse-sendredirect-permanent)

Comment: As I redirect from a servlet to a jsp page, jsp page is partially loaded , as in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12337624/incomplete-page-loaded-when-redirecting-from-the-servlet . I wanted the first thing to run when anyone hit _foo.com_ be the servlet. From the servlet I do a `response.sendRedirect("..")` to the index.jsp page of the website. But that misses out the css files and some text from the jsp page,leading to partial load of the page. But when I make the welcome page of the website to be index.jsp , everything works fine and page loads complete. what is wrong with the redirect ?

Answer (score 22):

The [`RequestDispatcher`](http://java.sun.com/products/servlet/2.5/docs/servlet-2_5-mr2/javax/servlet/RequestDispatcher.html) interface allows you to do a server side forward/include whereas [`sendRedirect()`](http://java.sun.com/products/servlet/2.5/docs/servlet-2_5-mr2/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html#sendRedirect(java.lang.String)) does a client side redirect. In a client side redirect, the server will send back an HTTP status code of `302` (temporary redirect) which causes the web browser to issue a brand new HTTP `GET` request for the content at the redirected location. In contrast, when using the [`RequestDispatcher`](http://java.sun.com/products/servlet/2.5/docs/servlet-2_5-mr2/javax/servlet/RequestDispatcher.html) interface, the include/forward to the new resource is handled entirely on the server side.

Comment: And the latter is actually `forward`, not redirect.

Answer (score 16):

> **The main important difference between the forward() and sendRedirect() method is that in case of forward(), redirect happens
>   at server end and not visible to client, but in case of
>   sendRedirect(), redirection happens at client end and it's visible to
>   client.**

[image]

Comment: A picture is worth a thousand words :)

Answer (score 5):

Either of these methods may be "better", i.e. more suitable, depending on what you want to do.

A server-side redirect is faster insofar as you get the data from a different page without making a round trip to the browser. But the URL seen in the browser is still the original address, so you're creating a little inconsistency there.

A client-side redirect is more versatile insofar as it can send you to a completely different server, or change the protocol (e.g. from HTTP to HTTPS), or both. And the browser is aware of the new URL. But it takes an extra back-and-forth between server and client.

Comment: This segment right here is not mentioned enough on the web:

"or change the protocol (e.g. from HTTP to HTTPS), or both"

Answer (score 3):

`SendRedirect()` will search the content between the servers. it is slow because it has to intimate the browser by sending the URL of the content. then browser will create a new request for the content within the same server or in another one.

`RquestDispatcher` is for searching the content within the server i think. its the server side process and it is faster compare to the `SendRedirect()` method. but the thing is that it will not intimate the browser in which server it is searching the required date or content, neither it will not ask the browser to change the URL in URL tab. so it causes little inconvenience to the user.

Answer (score 1):

Technically redirect should be used either if we need to transfer control to different domain or to achieve separation of task.

For example in the payment application
we do the PaymentProcess first and then redirect to displayPaymentInfo. If the client refreshes the browser only the displayPaymentInfo will be done again and PaymentProcess will not be repeated. But if we use forward in this scenario, both PaymentProcess and displayPaymentInfo will be re-executed sequentially, which may result in incosistent data.

For other scenarios, forward is efficient to use since as it is faster than sendRedirect

Answer (score 0):

Request Dispatcher is an Interface which is used to dispatch the request or response from web resource to the another web resource. It contains mainly two methods.

1. `request.forward(req,res)`: This method is used forward the request from one web resource to another resource. i.e from one servlet to another servlet or from one web application to another web appliacation.
2. `response.include(req,res)`: This method is used include the response of one servlet to another servlet

NOTE: BY using Request Dispatcher we can forward or include the request or responses with in the same server.

`request.sendRedirect()`: BY using this we can forward or include the request or responses across the different servers. In this the client gets a intimation while redirecting the page but in the above process the client will not get intimation

Answer (score 0):

Simply difference between `Forward(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response)` and `sendRedirect(String url)` is

**forward():**

1. The `forward()` method is executed in the server side.
2. The request is transfer to other resource within same server.
3. It does not depend on the client’s request protocol since the `forward ()` method is provided by the servlet container.
4. The request is shared by the target resource.
5. Only one call is consumed in this method.
6. It can be used within server.
7. We cannot see forwarded message, it is transparent.
8. The `forward()` method is faster than `sendRedirect()` method.
9. It is declared in `RequestDispatcher` interface.

**sendRedirect():**

1. The sendRedirect() method is executed in the client side.
2. The request is transfer to other resource to different server.
3. The sendRedirect() method is provided under HTTP so it can be used only with HTTP clients.
4. New request is created for the destination resource.
5. Two request and response calls are consumed.
6. It can be used within and outside the server.
7. We can see redirected address, it is not transparent.
8. The sendRedirect() method is slower because when new request is created old request object is lost.
9. It is declared in HttpServletResponse.