# Communication between servlets in Java

Tags: java, servlets

I have two web application running on same server.

I want to send objects from one servlet in Application1 to another servlet in Application2. How can i do that?

> 1. Will the session object be same for both the app if running on same
>      server?
> 2. How can i share the session object across the applications?
> 3. What if both web applications are on different server?

Please provide link of any good article which address the above issue since i am  unable to find one.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/665941/any-way-to-share-session-state-between-different-applications-in-tomcat

Comment: You can check this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3035656/communication-between-remote-servlets?rq=1)...