# Call several servlets

Tags: java, servlets

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I execute a sequence of servlets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3024949/how-do-i-execute-a-sequence-of-servlets)

I'd like to do something that seems to this, 
you click a button (POST method) -> call servlet1 (treatment 1) -> call servlet2 (treatment2) -> call servlet3 (treatment3 ).....

The second Servlet must await the completion of the first servlet and so on.

Comment: Duplicate of [How do I execute a sequence of servlets?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3024949/how-do-i-execute-a-sequence-of-servlets)

Answer (score 0):

Can you forward/redirect to the second servlet and chain them that way?  If not, I recommend refactoring to have them call methods rather than separate servlets.

Comment: Can you explain me how to forward/redirect to another servlet?  I think we can only redirect to jsp and not servlet

Comment: this posts shows how to use RequestDispatcher to do a forward: http://java.boot.by/wcd-guide/ch03s05.html

Comment: Right.  And I should also mention you use a forward when you want it as part of the same logical unit.  This shares the request parameters.  You use a redirect when you want to "break" it and have a browser refresh call only the last servlet.

Comment: If you really need to, use don't use forward, but use include. See also the linked dupe.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need RequestDispatcher's forward method:

http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/RequestDispatcher.html#forward(javax.servlet.ServletRequest,%20javax.servlet.ServletResponse)

> Forwards a request from a servlet to another resource (servlet, JSP file, or HTML file) on the server.

Comment: No, use include, not forward, see also the linked dupe.

Answer (score 0):

This "chain of responsibility" design is provided out-of-the box with servlet filters, instead of servlets. This way, instead of explicitely forwarding to the next servlet using a RequestDispatcher, you simply declare the filters in the desired order in web.xml and be able to simply add more or remove as needed (without touching the existing code).