# How do I send data between servlets?

Tags: java, database, servlets

I am pretty new to servlets and web development in general.

So basically I have a servlet that queries a database and returns some values, like a name. What I want is to turn the name into a link that opens a details page for that name (which another servlet would handle). How can I send the name to the other servlet so it can query a database for the relevant details?

Maybe I'm taking the wrong approach?

Edit: I am using Tomcat 5.5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass it as request parameter.

Either add it to the query string of the URL of the link to the other servlet which is then available by `request.getParameter("name")` in the `doGet()` method.

```
<a href="otherservlet?name=${name}">link</a>
```

Or add it as a hidden input field in a POST form which submits to the other servlet which is then available by `request.getParameter("name")` in the `doPost()` method.

```
<form action="otherservlet" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="name" value="${name}" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

#### See also:

- [Servlets info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info) - contains a Hello World

Comment: Yep. Servlets do not usually communicate with each other. They only serve requests to clients.

Comment: Sorry for another newbie question but what does "${whatever}" mean/do?

Comment: Thanks this actually worked well for me! I used the getParameter in the doGet() method. However, I did not need to add "${}" around the name.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand correctly, but you may look at javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher and forward the url to the second servlet.
The url could be created using the name:

```
http://myhost.mydomain/my.context/servlet2.do?name=John
```

Comment: He want to pass it by a link. Plus, forwarding isn't a good idea for inter servlet interaction. Including is better, see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3024949/how-do-i-execute-a-sequence-of-servlets

Answer (score 0):

I would **create the URL either in the first servlet or in a client** using a configurable template for the URL. This way both servlets are clearly separated - you can even have each one on different machine.