# How many ways are there on Redirect to next page in jsp?

Tags: java, jsp

in how many way can we redirect to next jsp page from one page to another page apart from following two ways,

```
RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("MyPage.jsp");
rd.forward(request, response);
```

and

```
response.sendRedirect("MyPage.jsp");
```

when i go to second page(MyPage.jsp) it has to load as fresh page from server side,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RequestDispatcher and sendRedirect are [different things](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2047122/requestdispatcher-interface-vs-sendredirect). If you want to

> load as fresh page from server side,

then RequestDispatcher won't work. The client (browser) still *thinks* the content comes from the original request.

Answer (score 0):

Take from JGuru:

http://www.jguru.com/faq/view.jsp?EID=376&page=2

```
You can also physically alter the Location HTTP header attribute, as shown below:

<%
response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_MOVED_PERMANENTLY);
String newLocn = "/newpath/index.html";
response.setHeader("Location",newLocn);
%>
```

Comment: I'm not sure why this is accepted. If this is accepted because it's in essence a different way, then it's okay. But if this is accepted because it's to be used as a real solution, then this should rather be downvoted. Scriptlets in a JSP are poor practice. Using `response.sendRedirect()` in a servlet is the only feasible way to send a redirect. The `requestDispatcher.forward()` doesn't send a redirect at all so it is definitely not one of the ways.

Answer (score 0):

Redirect has two types permanent and temporary redirect.