# return type int is not compatible with long error in java

Tags: java

I am taking two interfaces with same method signature and trying to implement in classes named Parent
and child.  However, i am confused why co-variant return types are not working here.

```
    interface First
    {
         public long show();
    }
    
    interface Second
    {
        public int show();
    }
    
    
    abstract class Parent implements First,Second
    {
        public long show(){
            return 10L;
        }
    }
    
    
    class Child extends Parent
    {
        public int show(){
            return 10;
        }
    }
    
    I get the following errors after compilation
    
    
      error: show() in Parent cannot implement show() in First
        public int show(){
                   ^
     return type int is not compatible with long
    error: show() in Child cannot implement show() in Second
        public long show(){
                    ^
  return type long is not compatible with int
                        ^
      return type long is not compatible with void
    
      But why int is not compatible with long?
```

Comment: *"Covariant return type works only for non-primitive return types."* - see e.g. https://www.tutorialspoint.com/Covariant-return-types-in-Java

Comment: did you check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9221650/a-forward-does-not-change-the-url-in-browser-address-bar) post ?

Comment: @Swati the post does not cover my question

Comment: Do not completely change an existing question. Create a new question if you have a new question.

Comment: It is strongly against the rules to change an existing question. The goal of this project is to create a database of questions and their answers. By changing the question rather than create a new question, you are subverting this. In addition, the answer to your original question will look rather silly after you change the question so completely.

Answer (score 0):

Covariant return types are described in the [Language Spec](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.5):

> Return types may vary among methods that override each other if the return types are reference types. The notion of return-type-substitutability supports covariant returns, that is, the specialization of the return type to a subtype.
>
> A method declaration d1 with return type R1 is return-type-substitutable for another method d2 with return type R2 iff any of the following is true:
>
> - If R1 is void then R2 is void.
> - If R1 is a primitive type then R2 is identical to R1.
> - If R1 is a reference type then one of the following is true: ...

`int` is a narrower type than `long`, but as it is primitive but not identical to `long`, it is not considered return-type-substitutable.