# Can we dispatch request to an HTML inside servlet

Tags: java, servlets, requestdispatcher

Is this possible?

```
RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("index.html");
rd.forward(request, response);
```

Comment: @Thilo can't we use responce.sendRedirect("index.html") instead..I mean which would be better option?

Comment: they should both work. What is better depends on if you want to redirect or not. For example, the URL would change if you do.

Comment: Would you like `forward` the control to another resource typically a web component? If yes, then use a `RequestDispatcher.forward()`. If you like to redirect to a completely new resource, use a `sendRedirect()`. Hoping that you're clear about the differences between them. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2047122/requestdispatcher-interface-vs-sendredirect

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. you can dispatch a request to a HTML page.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it will work. You can get the request dispatcher for static/dynamic pages.