# How to display list of Date from servlet in selector tag in jsp page

Tags: java, jquery, html, jsp, servlets

I am trying to dynamically generate a list of dates without duplicates in JSP to display in a selector tag.

In my servlet class:

```
query = " SELECT * FROM visits";
prepStatement = connection.prepareStatement(query);

results = prepStatement.executeQuery();
Set<Date> vdates = new HashSet<>();
while(results.next()){
    vdates.add(results.getDate("date"));                
}
Date[] dates = vdates.toArray(new Date[vdates.size()]);
out.println(vdates);
request.setAttribute("dates", dates);
RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("/js/selectorJSP.jsp");
dispatcher.forward(request, response);
```

In my selectorJSP file:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>JSP Selector Page</title>
    <script src="js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Hello World!</h1>
    <select>
        <option value="AllRecords">${dates[0]}</option>
    </select>
    <input type="button" onclick="" value="Download">
</body>
</html>
```

The result is that it just shows an empty field, I am trying to show one to make sure it works and make a loop to show all available dates in selector but not available.

Comment: How are you getting variable "dates" in JSP? What does <% request.getAttribute("dates"); %> or What does <% request.getAttribute("dates[0]"); %>  To read them in loop you can loop on it like <c:forEach var="date" items="${dates}"> and put required checks

Comment: i thought if we add variables to the request in servlets, we can access those variables using '${variablename} in jsp page. i tried the request.getAttribute(""); both of them still the value in selector is empty. I dont really understand that much about the c:forEach so i havent tried that, i will do after getting variable value to jsp page

Comment: Check this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12351107/request-attributes-not-available-in-jsp-page-when-using-sendredirect-from-a-serv