# Send response and request from JSP to servlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, request, response

How can I send my response and request object from a jsp file to a servlet by code? I don't want to submit a form or so.

I tried it with:

```
response.setRedirect("my page"):
```

But then it says:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.http.client.HttpResponseException: Moved Temporarily
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicResponseHandler.handleResponse(BasicResponseHandler.java:68)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicResponseHandler.handleResponse(BasicResponseHandler.java:54)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:945)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:919)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:910)
    at com.xx.xx.client.Client.sendPOSTRequest(Client.java:185)
    at com.xx.xx.client.Client.main(Client.java:46)
```

**As clarification**: I have a client that sends a post request to a JSP file. This JSP file parses a file and puts the needed information into the session. I want to call a servlet from this jsp file to add something into the database. I think this error code is thrown by this line `String responseBody = httpclient.execute(httppost, responseHandler);`

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do. You're getting a 302 back; back from what? Are you trying to use the response from your HttpClient request directly?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the [RequestDispatcher](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/RequestDispatcher.html) `forward(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response)`

> Forwards a request from a servlet to another resource (servlet, JSP file, or HTML file) on the server.

You can do it like this:

```
ServletContext context= getServletContext();
RequestDispatcher rd= context.getRequestDispatcher("/YourServlet");
rd.forward(request, response);
```

**UPDATE**

Also note on your code that you have `response.setRedirect` instead of `response.sendRedirect(...)` but note that this method will not work as you want it to because it just asks the browser to make a new request to your servlet rather than forward your `request` and `response` object to that servlet .  See [RequestDispatcher.forward() vs HttpServletResponse.sendRedirect()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2047122/requestdispatcher-interface-vs-sendredirect) for more info

Comment: I tried this before, but I don't see that there is also a request to the specified servlet. Any idea why?

Comment: Your code works perfectly. The output was just inside another console. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 2):

You can just use `<jsp:include>` on a servlet URL.

```html
<jsp:include page="/servletURL" />
```

The servlet `doXxx()` method will just be invoked with the current request/response. Note that the servlet cannot forward to another JSP afterwards. It has to write directly to the response, or to set some request/session attributes which the JSP can intercept on *after* the `<jsp:include>` line.

Note that this is bad design. You're abusing a JSP as a front controller. It should be the other way round. The servlet should act as a front controller and the JSP should act as a view. The client should send the request to the servlet URL directly instead of to some JSP file. The servlet should perform the business job and finally forward to a JSP to let it present the results in HTML. See also [our servlets tag wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info) for some Hello World examples.