# Why can web.xml welcome-file be located inside WEB-INF

Tags: jsp, jakarta-ee, web.xml

I have read that a `jsp` file inside `WEB-INF` cannot be accessed from outside (it must be called from a `Servlet`).

But, why can the `welcome-file` in `web.xml` file, point to a file inside the `WEB-INF` directory? because this way the file can be accessed from outside :

```xml
<welcome-file-list>  
    <welcome-file>WEB-INF/page.jsp</welcome-file>  
</welcome-file-list>
```

I'm testing with `Google App engine` and default Servlet container `Jetty 6`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because the welcome file is served by a [`RequestDispatcher#forward()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/RequestDispatcher.html#forward%28javax.servlet.ServletRequest,%20javax.servlet.ServletResponse%29) call. As evidence, do you see `/WEB-INF/page.jsp` appearing in browser's address bar? No? Then it's already most definitely not a direct request. If you attempt to request it directly, you'll see that you get a 404.

#### See also:

- [RequestDispatcher.forward() vs HttpServletResponse.sendRedirect()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2047122/requestdispatcher-interface-vs-sendredirect/2048640#2048640)
- [Servlets wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info) - contains Hello World examples illustrating real world use cases for `forward()`

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, you seem to be basically abusing the `<welcome-file>` to have a "homepage file". There it is not intented for. It's intented to specify the sole filename of the folder's file you'd like to serve up when *any* folder is been requested, such as `/`, `/foo/`, `/foo/bar/`, etc. If you specify `index.jsp`, then the `/index.jsp`, `/foo/index.jsp`, `/foo/bar/index.jsp`, etc will transparently be served up by a forward without a change in URL.

Comment: Does it mean that there can be multiple `welcome-file` by folder ? or multiple `web.xml` files, each specific to a certain folder ?

Comment: Both is possible (look, why is `<welcome-file-list>` called exactly like that, "*welcome file **list***"?). Multiple `web.xml` is also possible, but the others must be called `web-fragment.xml` and be included in JARs in `/WEB-INF/lib`.