# forward(request, response) reveals user data in the address bar

Tags: jsp, servlets, response.redirect, forward

I have a login form and a servlet that makes the login. If the user is valid, i redirect him to the next page

```
response.sendRedirect("welcome.jsp");
```

Also i want to send an object to this page, so i replace the sendRedirect with this

```
request.setAttribute("notes", notesObject)
disp = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/welcome.jsp");
disp.forward(request, response);
```

The problem now is that now, when a user logs in (e.g. user / 111), in the address bar i have this:

```
localhost:8084/WebApplication2/loginServlet?username=user&password=111&action=LOGIN
```

but when i used the Sendredirect i had only the `localhost:8084/WebApplication2/welcome.jsp`

The login Servlet:

```
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws ServletException, IOException {
//code...
```

The jsp file:

```
 <form action="loginServlet">
//code...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is not with `forward()` or `sendRedirect()`, it's with how you are sending the data from the `HTML` form.

Remember, the `<form>` tag uses `GET` method as default HTTP method. Since you haven't given any method explicitly, it will use `GET` method.

See [this link](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.3):

```
<!ATTLIST FORM
  %attrs;                              -- %coreattrs, %i18n, %events --
  action      %URI;          #REQUIRED -- server-side form handler --
  method      (GET|POST)     GET       -- HTTP method used to submit the form--
  enctype     %ContentType;  "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
  accept      %ContentTypes; #IMPLIED  -- list of MIME types for file upload --
  name        CDATA          #IMPLIED  -- name of form for scripting --
  onsubmit    %Script;       #IMPLIED  -- the form was submitted --
  onreset     %Script;       #IMPLIED  -- the form was reset --
  accept-charset %Charsets;  #IMPLIED  -- list of supported charsets --
  >
```

Now, with `GET` request, all your form data goes as a part of your *query string*, that is why you are seeing those data there. You should change the method to `POST`.

```
<form action="loginServlet" method = "POST">
```

---

The reason why you didn't see the data while using `sendRedirect()` is that, with `response.sendRedirect()` the client creates and sends a new request. So, your old request *URI* is no longer there. With `forward()` this is not the case. The *URI* doesn't changes, and you see the original *URI*, with the query string.

> when i used the Sendredirect i had only the `localhost:8084/WebApplication2/welcome.jsp`

As I said, the *URI* changes, that you can see. Hence you don't see the query string, that came with original *URI*.

**See also:**

- [HTTP Methods: GET vs. POST](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp)
- [RequestDispatcher.forward() vs HttpServletResponse.sendRedirect()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2047122/1679863)

Comment: In order to work, i had to delete this code `if(request.getQueryString().equals("logoute"))`. Otherwise i had an error HTTP 500, threw exception java.lang.NullPointerException. Do you know why? @Rohitjain

Comment: @yaylitzis. Well, now since you are using `POST`, you won't get the parameter in query string. And hence you get `NPE`. You should now get the parameters using `request.getParameter({form-element-name})`