# Page redirection at server side, what options do I have?

Tags: java, redirect, servlet-filters

I just wonder if there is some other options to perform a page redirection. What I basically have is for example some properties:

```
test.goroPageA
```

and then in case if this property is true then go to .../test/pageA/example/showPageA.html
otherwise  go to .../test/common/example/showSimplePage.html

The main idea is to use smth like this:

```
public class RedirectionFilter implements Filter
```

But are there some other options?

Thank you

Comment: You don't say which technologies, if any, you are using. How are you serving the pages? Are they static HTML or do you use a `Servlet` to template them?

Answer (score 0):

You can use RequestDispatcher [PageRedirection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2047122/requestdispatcher-interface-vs-sendredirect) refer the link to clear your doubt.