# How can i show Mandatory Symbol and text required tab if i miss the field?

Tags: jsp, validation

```
<body>        
    <%
        out.println(" UserName:<input type=\"text\" id=\"s1\" size=\"10\" name=\"s1 \" > ");

        out.println("Password:<input type=\"password\" id=\"s2\" size=\"10\" name=\"s2\" >");

        out.println("<button onclick=\"Myfunction()\">Submit</button>");
    %>
</body>
```

This is my Jsp page,when i goes to Password tab ,it has to show mandatory symbol * and text box beside username that field is mandadtory. How can i do this ,anybody guide me please,thanks for your help?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `jquery` validation and from your code i could see that you are constructing the html page inside your scriptlets . thats really a bad technique , you could use [RequestDispatcher or sendRedirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2047122/requestdispatcher-interface-vs-sendredirect) .

Hope this helps !!