# difference betweern return plain modelandview and return a redirect modelandview

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-webflow

I have just learnt Spring MVC webflow. I am confused with this:

```
return new ModelAndView("test");
return new ModelAndView("redirect:test");
```

Is the redirect one just like `response.sendRedirect()`?
And I just check the Spring reference, actually, the `return new RedirectView()` does the same as `response.sendRedirect()`. So what's difference between these three?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to compare ModelAndView("test") and ModelAndView("redirect:test")
to servlet framework. The first one will be similar to RequestDispatcher
and the latter will be similar to request.sendRedirect()
If you want to know the difference between requestdispatcher and sendredirect,
there's the answer for [that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2048640/2247309)

Even though the end result of "redirect:test" is to call HttpServletResponse.sendRedirect(),
RedirectView object gives you convenience and a little bit more functionalities.
IMO, using servlet API directly in the framework is probably not a good idea except
you want to hack some stuff or workaround something.

> The RedirectView issues an HttpServletResponse.sendRedirect() call that returns to 
>   the client browser as an HTTP redirect. By default all model attributes are considered 
>   to be exposed as URI template variables in the redirect URL. Of the remaining attributes
>   those that are primitive types or collections/arrays of primitive types are automatically 
>   appended as query parameters. 
>   http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html

Anyway, in spring MVC, there are ususally more than one way to do the same thing.
It's just the matter of coding style.
For example,

```
public String doSomething(Model model){
    return "test";
}
public ModelAndView i_am_similar_to_doSomething(){
    return new ModelAndView("test");
}

//You can guess that you can do the same thing with redirect.
```

There are some more ways to do something like this but my suggestion is that 
try to stick to the same style for the whole application.

Comment: so what do you mean is that both ModelAndView("test") and ModelAndView("redirect:test") works in the same way, it's only the coding style matter.

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood you. I updated my answer and hope that help.

Comment: please read my question clearly, my question is that is there any difference with these two ModelAndView("test") and ModelAndView("redirect:test"), but not return "test" and return ModelAndView("test").

Comment: The first paragraph could answer your question. The rest of my answer is to show the flexibility of Spring MVC. Sorry if the rest part made you more confusing. Actually, your question is nothing about Spring MVC except the API that you use. Your question should be "What is different between forward and redirect?"

Comment: Sorry to the my confusion, as i have checked, in Spring MVC, RedirectView() actually does the response.sendredirect, so what do you mean is that return RedirectView("test") is the same as return ModelAndView("redirect:test")?

Comment: I have check again, as you said, ModelAndView("redirect:test")is the same as RedirectView("test"). Thanks for your anwser.