# Servlet won't redirect me

Tags: java, jquery, jsp, servlets

i have logout button and when its pressed i want to return to main page but it stays on current page. although i receive response in chrome developer tools.

**userinfo.jsp**

```
<input type="button" onclick="logout()" value="Logout" class="btn" style="margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 10px;"/>
```

**logout.js**

```
function logout(){

    $.post("Logout");

}
```

**Logout.java servlet**

```
public class Logout extends HttpServlet {
    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        PrintWriter out = null;

        try{


            HttpSession sess = request.getSession();
            if(sess != null){

            sess.invalidate();

            }

            response.sendRedirect("index.html");
```

[image: Here's Response]

Comment: What response do you receive?

Comment: tehre's picture up there

Comment: I do not know jquery so well but I think that this call is responsible for behavior. Can you test normal form without javascript?

Comment: `$.post("Logout");` is an ajax call. Why would the page redirect?

Comment: solved it. i used windows.location instead of ajax call. thanx @Subir Kumar Sao

Comment: If you redirect inside a servlet being hit by Ajax, that does not redirect the page that sent the Ajax request.  It redirects the Ajax response only.  And you aren't even reading the response to the Ajax request!

Answer (score 2):

Use `RequestDispatcher` instead of using `sendRedirect`

**For Example:**

```
RequestDispatcher reqDispatcher = req.getRequestDispatcher("pathToResource/MyPage.jsp");
reqDispatcher.forward(req,res);
```

Read why and when to use each of [`RequestDispatcher` and `sendRedirect`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2047122/requestdispatcher-interface-vs-sendredirect)

Comment: How is this an answer if the OP wants to redirect?

Comment: i also used dispatcher instead of redirect

Comment: I agree, the problem was in client side, this answer is irrelevant to the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="button" onclick="window.location.href='/path/servlet.java'" value="Logout" class="btn" style="margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 10px;"/>
```