# Jsp reloading page not working

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, web, web-development-server

i have signup page when i first submitting the data in form action i am sending it to a servlet 
before submiting my url is **Localhost:\Shop

> **

```
<form action="signup" method="post">
```

and in this servlet i have businesses logic after submitting it i am forwarding it to my index page by

> `
>   request.getrequestdispatcher("index.jsp").forward(request,response);

now my URL is 
**localhost:\Shop\SignUp**
now when i refresh this page it gives me warning

**Confirmation Form Resolution**

How do i avoid this problem ????

Comment: are you submitting the form through javascript?

Comment: no sir i am submitting in jsp

Comment: Are you sure it give **"Confirmation Form Resolution"** or Confirmation Form Resubmission ?

Comment: see my answer , update the question if you need any explantion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you are posting the same request to the server as you are using RequestDispatcher method.

You need to understand the differences between [RequestDispatcher.forward() vs HttpServletResponse.sendRedirect()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2047122/requestdispatcher-interface-vs-sendredirect)

So you need to use the `sendRedirect()` method to create a new request

```
response.sendRedirect("index.jsp");
```

Hope this helps!!

Comment: Sir but i'm setting attribute in the request if use Sendredirect i will not be able to set the attribute

Comment: You can indeed set the attribute . But you need to pass the value as the  value as `query string` . (i.e) however a bad idea . but you will get the warning window for `forwarding` , but that wont impact your result

Comment: actually i have function Boolean add_customer() which returns true if record successfully inserted i am passing that true value to jsp page through setting the attribue in request.i am generating a pop up on home page if record inserted successfully.

Comment: so you dont want the pop-up to be shown after you reload every time , so  you can set the value in the query string like this `response.sendRedirect("index.jsp?booVal="+valueHere);`

Comment: Ok and who do i get that value from url

Comment: It is same as you done for the previous case . you can get the value from this `booVal` attribute . For example , if you use EL like ${booVal}

Comment: what kind of syntex is this i have never studied before can you write down the complete syntex

Comment: that is expression language . if you are using java codes in your jsp [Read this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files)