# output of try and catch block should be printed in 2 different jsp pages

Tags: jsp

I am trying to print the output of a java file to a jsp file.

```
for(String x : list)
{
    try {
        output 1
    }
    catch {
        output 2
    }
}
```

The `output 1` should go to `x.jsp` file
The `output 2` should go to `y.jsp` file

Where do I give `response.Redirect(x.jsp)` and `response.Redirect(y.jsp)`?

If I give each statements within each block/try and catch) it will throw error:

> cannot redirect after committing

Any help is much appreciated. Let me know if you don't understand my question correctly.

Comment: Don't print out a bunch of stuff before trying to redirect. If you're going to redirect, make it simple. And make sure to do `return;` right after response.sendRedirect too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to do it.
selection of radio buttons

```
if(radio value==(value of 1st radio button))
{
for(String x : list)
{
   try {
    output 1
      RequestDispatcher dispatcher =request.getRequestDispatcher("1st.jsp");
      dispatcher.forward(request, response);
      return;
}
catch {
    output 2
      RequestDispatcher dispatcher =request.getRequestDispatcher("2nd.jsp");
      dispatcher.forward(request, response);
      return;
  }
  }
  }
 else{

 for(String x : list)
  {
  try {
    output 1
      RequestDispatcher dispatcher =request.getRequestDispatcher("1st.jsp");
      dispatcher.forward(request, response);
      return;
}
catch {
    output 2
      RequestDispatcher dispatcher =request.getRequestDispatcher("2nd.jsp");
      dispatcher.forward(request, response);
      return;
}
 }
}
```

based on this it will go to one of the jsp pages depending upon the selection of radio buttons.

I hope this will help people in the future too.

thanks all for helping me out.

Answer (score 0):

`response.sendRedirect()` method creates a new request every time , why dont you use the `RequestDispatcher` and add a return statement to it .

see this [RequestDispatcher.forward() vs HttpServletResponse.sendRedirect()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2047122/requestdispatcher-interface-vs-sendredirect)

so you may rewrite your code as ,

```
for(String x : list)
{
    try {
        output 1
          RequestDispatcher dispatcher =request.getRequestDispatcher("1st.jsp");
          dispatcher.forward(request, response);
          return;
    }
    catch {
        output 2
          RequestDispatcher dispatcher =request.getRequestDispatcher("2nd.jsp");
          dispatcher.forward(request, response);
          return;
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I guess this should work. I need to create a radio button in jsp and 1st option should go to try option and print 1st.jsp and 2nd option should go to catch and print 2nd.jsp.Should I create a if statement for the radio button and go through the try catch blocks.