# How to change the project URL to the last servlet called?

Tags: jakarta-ee, servlets

From a servlet "servlet.html", I can call another servlet "servlet2.html" like this:

```
dispatcher = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/servlet2.html");
```

However, in the brouzer, the URL is from the first servlet:

http://localhost:8080/project/servlet.html

I would like it to be the URL of the current servlet.

http://localhost:8080/project/servlet2.html

Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

What you want is to perform redirect: `response.sendRedirect("/servlet2.html")`.

**TL;DR;**

Dispatcher will just pass request to another servlet, so client does not see any change.

When you are performing `redirect` then server is sending response with HTTP code 302 and parameter `Location` with full URL to `servlet2.html`. When a web browser will recieve this kind of response it will perform another request  to URL given in `Location` parameter.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2047122/requestdispatcher-interface-vs-sendredirect) you can find more explanations.

Comment: when I wrote response.sendRedirect("/servlet2.html"), it gives an error saying localhost:8080/servlet2.html cannot be found, which is true because that URL is wrong, but when I remove the "/" like so response.sendRedirect("servlet2.html") it now works. Can you explain why it worked without the "/"?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. "/" refers to root of the aplication. Without it you refer to a relative path in relation to path of the original request.