# How to redirect page to a url which is the same url as current with and additional parameter appended?

Tags: jsp, servlets, redirect

I wish to redirect my code to the same page with an extra parameter in the url if a few conditions are met. How would i do so?

I tried using response.setHeader but it is not not working.

```
if(request.getParameter("lang")==null && UserProfileHelper.readCookie(request,"bha_code")!=null){
    langCode=UserProfileHelper.readCookie(request,"bha_code");
    if(langCode!=null && langCode!="en")
    {
       String url=CafeUtils.getCurrentURLNonUFT8(request);
       String[] urlNew = url.split(fullLailaURL);
       url=fullLailaURL+"/"+langCode+urlNew[1];
       response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_MOVED_TEMPORARILY);
       response.setHeader("Refresh", url);
    }
}
```

I want the url in the browser to reflect the new one.

SC_MOVED_TEMPORARILY= 302

Comment: check if `RequestDispatcher` can achieve this task.

Comment: @Vishrant: Nope, OP clearly want to send a redirect, not a forward. OP explicitly used the term "redirect" and explicitly stated *"I want the url in the browser to reflect the new one."*. In case you have no idea what that means, head to http://stackoverflow.com/a/2048640

Answer (score 0):

This is wrong.

```
response.setHeader("Refresh", url);
```

The HTTP spec [clearly](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.3.3) says you must use the `Location` header field.

```
response.setHeader("Location", url);
```

It can even be done simpler. Instead of the two lines,

```
response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_MOVED_TEMPORARILY);
response.setHeader("Location", url);
```

you can just use the standard [`HttpServletResponse#sendRedirect()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html#sendRedirect-java.lang.String-) method.

```
response.sendRedirect(url);
```

See also its [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html#sendRedirect-java.lang.String-) (emphasis mine):

> Sends a temporary redirect response to the client using the specified redirect **location URL** and clears the buffer. The buffer will be replaced with the data set by this method. Calling this method **sets the status code to SC_FOUND 302** (Found).