# Java servlet not redirecting properly

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have two pages jsp pages First one is **AppLogin.jsp** and other one is **Login.jsp**

I want that when i click on Submit button of **AppLogin.jsp** page, i want redirect to **Login.jsp** page with **password** value
and check this value on page load of **Login.jsp** page.

For this i did following code
but the  below code did not work.

**I don't want to use Session and append value on url**.

**AppLogin.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>App Login</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="loginServlet" method="post">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Application Name</td>
                <td><input type="text" value="" name="txtApplication" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Username</td>
                <td><input type="text" value="" name="txtUsername" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Password</td>
                <td><input type="text" value="" name="txtPassword" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr align="center">
                <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</body>
</html>

public class LoginServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res)
            throws ServletException, ClientProtocolException {
        try {
            String password = req.getParameter("txtPassword");
            req.setAttribute("crendential",password);
            RequestDispatcher rd = req.getRequestDispatcher("Login.jsp");
            rd.forward(req,res);
        }

        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("LoginServletException>>>>>>>>>>" + e);
        }
    }
}
```

**Login.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Login</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="saveServlet" method="post">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Application :</td>
                <td><input type="text" value="" name="txtApplication" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Username :</td>
                <td><input type="text" value="" name="txtUsername" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Password :</td>
                <td><input type="text" value="" name="txtPassword" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr align="center">
                <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</body>
</html>

public class SaveServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res)
            throws ServletException {
        try {
            String crendential = (String) req.getAttribute("crendential");
            System.out.println("crendential>>>>>>>>>>" + crendential);
        }

        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("LoginServletException>>>>>>>>>>" + e);
        }
    }

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
        String crendential = (String) req.getAttribute("crendential");
        System.out.println("crendential>>>>>>>>>>" + crendential);
    }
}
```

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
    <display-name>xyz</display-name>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>login</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>xyz.io.LoginServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>login</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/loginServlet</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>save</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>xyz.io.SaveServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>save</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/Login.jsp</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>AppLogin.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

I am using Java with Eclipse Mars.

Comment: Did you try to store value in HttpSession and use response.sendRedirect in doGet() ?

Comment: can you really define a `servlet` inside of a `.jsp`?

Comment: What error you are getting?

Comment: What is not working? Where is the redirect? I can see only a forward.

Comment: @tak3sh my url is change to /Login.jsp, but it showing me blank.

Comment: If you get a blank screen, have you checked your logfile for exceptions?

Comment: @tak3shi there is no error.

Comment: Obviously it will show blank page because you have not written anything in `SaveServlet` look in console in eclipse is there anything printing there?

Comment: @Naman I have to redirect to Login.jsp when i click on Submit button of AppLogin.jsp page with password value.

Comment: Change web.xml to `<servlet-mapping><servlet-name>save</servlet-name><url-pattern>/saveServlet</url-pattern></servlet-mapping>` then it will redirect to `Login.jsp`

Comment: @Naman when i change my code it redirect me to "Login.jsp" properly but my url show change to "/loginServlet" and my doGet method of Login.jsp not call.

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2047122/requestdispatcher-forward-vs-httpservletresponse-sendredirect , this will solve why url show /loginservlet

Comment: @Naman I already read this, so can we have any other option to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Login.jsp has a request attribute "credentials." To pass this value to the saveServlet there would be two possibilities:

- Store the credentials instead as session attribute
- Pass the credentials on in Login.jsp, say as hidden form input field.

  ```
  <input type="hidden" name="credentials" value="${credentials}">
  ```

---

***Correction:***

I did miss the somewhat hard to digest web.xml with its servlet mappings.

In general how it *often* is done

- A servlet mapping:

  xyz.io.DisplayLoginServlet
  /login

  xyz.io.ProcessLoginServlet
  /authorize
- DisplayLoginServlet

  doGet
      prepares the form data (request attributes)
      forwards to some displayLogin.jsp

  doPost
      validates the form, possibly redisplays the form with error messages (doGet)
      otherwise when successfully done,
          set session attributes
          and **redirect** to the home page.
- displayLogin.jsp

  (posts to the same servlet)

And so on.

The mapped servlet URLs do not relate to JSPs.
The servlet is the entry point, the **controller**. It prepares the data **model**, puts them in the request attributes, and forwards to some JSP, the **view**. The servlet can on successfull login use an other JSP for instance.

Here we *redirect* after a successfull post. That is the brower is told to get the redirected page as answer. The effect is that the user cannot reload the page and effectively re-post the HTML form.

I think making a clean distinction will already help.

Comment: how can i pass value to Login.jsp?

Comment: user3441151 has already mentioned in `web.xml`, pattern `/Login.jsp` is being forwarded to `SaveServlet`.

Comment: @JoopEggen my url is change to /Login.jsp, but it showing me blank.

Comment: @user3441151 I admit skipping web.xml.

Comment: @user3441151 rather than trying to explain the knot in the control flow, I tried to add a how-to,