# Add text java requestDispatcher

Tags: java, jsp, requestdispatcher

I want to direct the user back to the previous page with the same get in the url

```
if (somecheck) { 
 req.getRequestDispatcher("register.jsp?email="+req.getParameter("email")).forward(req, resp);
}
```

But this directs the user to `"/register.jsp"` instead of `"/register.jsp?email=testemail@mail.com"`

How can i add the email to the url?

Comment: `email` parameter is already in your request. Just read it in register jsp from request object.

Comment: @Faraz Durrani 
But i want it in the url

Comment: Then you should use `response.sendRedirect("register.jsp?email="+req.getParameter("email"));` only redirect can change actual url (or you may do it in js). Forward doesn't change the url, it gives the response of requested resource.

Comment: Please, see detailed explanation here [RequestDispatcher.forward() vs HttpServletResponse.sendRedirect()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2047122/requestdispatcher-forward-vs-httpservletresponse-sendredirect)

Comment: Unfortunately not, `sendRedirect()` doesn't keeps track of any parameters sent in initial request. Roughly, it goes back to browser and forces it to send another request using url passed to `sendRedirect`

Comment: @Anton Dovzhenko Thanks for the help, i got it working now

Comment: You are welcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is using `response.sendRedirect("register.jsp?email="+req.getParameter("email"));` thanks to Anton Dovzhenko

Answer (score 0):

```
ServletContext context = request.getServletContext();
String path = "/register.jsp?email="+request.getParameter("email");
RequestDispatcher rd = context.getRequestDispatcher(path);
rd.include(request, response);
```