# CSS linking is not working in jsp

Tags: html, css, jsp, servlets

[image] my code is 
AddBookCategory.java

```
    package com.bhim.admin;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
    import java.sql.SQLException;
    import javax.servlet.ServletException;
    import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

    import com.bhim.dbConnection.DBConnection;

    @WebServlet(name = "category", urlPatterns = "/addCategory")
    public class AddBookCategory extends HttpServlet {
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)throws 
    ServletException, IOException {
    // for checking 
    System.out.println("reached here...");
    DBConnection dbConnection=new DBConnection();
    try {
    dbConnection.open();
    String query="insert into `bookcategory`(`c_name`) values(?)";
    PreparedStatement preparedStatement=dbConnection.gePreparedStatement(query);
    preparedStatement.setString(1, req.getParameter("category"));
    int i=preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
    if(i>0)  {
    System.out.println("Insert Successfully");
    //  req.getRequestDispatcher("admin/addCategory.jsp").forward(req, resp);
    resp.sendRedirect("admin/addCategory.jsp");

            }
    else{
    System.out.println("insertion Failed...");
     }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();

        } catch (SQLException e) 
    e.printStackTrace();
            }
            }
         }
```

addCategory.jsp

```
<jsp:include page="adminHeader.jsp" />
<center>
   <div class="content">
    <form action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/addCategory" method="get">
       <table class="full" border="0">
        <tr>
            <td><h2>Category Name</h2></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td><input type="text" name="category" /></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
           <td><input type="submit" value="Add Category" /></td>
         </tr>
    </table>
  </form>
 </div>
</center>
<jsp:include page="../footer.jsp" />
```

adminheader.jsp

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link href="../css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <title>Bus Booking System</title> 
</head>
<body>
 <div id='wrapper'>
    <div class="banner">
       <h1>Online Library Management System</h1>

       <% // Using session...
       HttpSession session1 = request.getSession();
       String user = (String) session1.getAttribute("user");
       %>
    <span class="session"> Welcome:<%=user%>
    </span>
  </div>

  <div class="menu">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="index.jsp" class="current">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="bookCategory.jsp">Book Category</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Books</a></li>
      <li><a href="#feedback.html"> User Mgmt</a></li>
      <li><a href="#about.html">Search Book </a></li>
      <li><a href="#about.html">Check allocated Book</a></li>
      <li><a href="login.jsp"> Notification</a></li>
      <li><a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/index.jsp">Logout</a>
     </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I am trying to forward page from servlet to jsp using RequestDispatcher CSS is not work but i also try sendRedirect css is working.Give me suggestion why css is not working when using requestDispatcher.

Comment: where is the code for index.jsp?

Comment: @jmmontero plz see edited code and give me suggestion

Comment: Also, would help to know the directory structure of your project.

Comment: @jmmontero yes. i am also post screenshot

Comment: Don't see it? Did you look into my answer?

Comment: @jmmontero yes but that code is not working in admin folder

Comment: can you try it again!

Answer (score 0):

The problem I found was in the way you include your css file. If you debug it using Chrome you should see a 404 error loading the style.css file. Try this:

addCategory.jsp

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link href="../css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <title>Bus Booking System</title> 
</head>
<body>
<jsp:include page="adminHeader.jsp" />
<center>
   <div class="content">
    <form action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/addCategory" method="get">
       <table class="full" border="0">
        <tr>
            <td><h2>Category Name</h2></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td><input type="text" name="category" /></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
           <td><input type="submit" value="Add Category" /></td>
         </tr>
    </table>
  </form>
 </div>
</center>
<jsp:include page="../footer.jsp" />
```

adminHeader.jsp

```
 <div id='wrapper'>
<div class="banner">
   <h1>Online Library Management System</h1>

   <% // Using session...
   HttpSession session1 = request.getSession();
   String user = (String) session1.getAttribute("user");
   %>
<span class="session"> Welcome:<%=user%>
</span>
  </div>

  <div class="menu">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="index.jsp" class="current">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="bookCategory.jsp">Book Category</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Books</a></li>
      <li><a href="#feedback.html"> User Mgmt</a></li>
      <li><a href="#about.html">Search Book </a></li>
      <li><a href="#about.html">Check allocated Book</a></li>
      <li><a href="login.jsp"> Notification</a></li>
      <li><a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/index.jsp">Logout</a>
     </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: @Binod Pant you can also check this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2047122/requestdispatcher-forward-vs-httpservletresponse-sendredirect

Comment: @Binod Pant Did that work for you?

Comment: when i use requestDispatcher is not working but when i use send redirect css is working.

Comment: In order to work with requestDispatcher you will have to use: `String path = request.getContextPath()`