# Redirect url doesn't have token that I send

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

Does a post always use redirect to respond to a request. If so, how can I ensure that the response headers are also carried forward to the redirected url? Currently, I'm setting a JWT token in the response headers that I send but the redirected url doesn't contain the token. Can someone tell me how I can ensure that I get the JWT token so that I can use it in my further requests.

```
String token = JWT.create()
                .withSubject(((LdapUserDetails) authentication.getPrincipal()).getUsername())
                .withExpiresAt(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + EXPIRATION_TIME))
                .sign(HMAC512(SECRET.getBytes()));
        response.addHeader(HEADER_STRING, TOKEN_PREFIX + token);

        Object redirectURLObject = request.getSession().getAttribute(REDIRECT_URL_SESSION_ATTRIBUTE_NAME);

        if(redirectURLObject != null)
            setDefaultTargetUrl(redirectURLObject.toString());
        else{
            setDefaultTargetUrl("http://localhost:8000");
        }
request.getSession().removeAttribute(REDIRECT_URL_SESSION_ATTRIBUTE_NAME);
        super.onAuthenticationSuccess(request, response, authentication);
```

[image: With JWT token before redirect]

[image: After Redirect- Without JWT]

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure about `super.onAuthenticationSuccess(request, response, authentication);` line, it is most likely the culprit.

I assume that your class is something like `extends
        AbstractAuthenticationTargetUrlRequestHandler implements
        AuthenticationSuccessHandler {`

If you dig deeper you'll find inside `handle` method in `AbstractAuthenticationTargetUrlRequestHandler` class which has this line:

`redirectStrategy.sendRedirect(request, response, targetUrl);` which will redirect within from your browser with 302 status.

If you understand this problem, it's not possible to have it in the header. There are other ways: you could make AJAX call from frontend, or returning JSON with JWT in header or having forwarding without sendRedirect.

May be you are looking to forward the request ([RequestDispatcher.forward() vs HttpServletResponse.sendRedirect()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2047122/requestdispatcher-forward-vs-httpservletresponse-sendredirect))

Comment: I actually solved it by removing the redirect part. But the next request doesnt have the header. Should the front end set it manually by picking it from the response ?

Comment: Please update your question with full code and flow. I can't assume on what you did.

Comment: I got the answer, acutually im going to another url. So i have to save it and insert the token in the header manually.