# Spring-security: Is there any way to verify url parameter with cookie from client?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I have used form-login and login success in Spring security 4.2.

Then client will send cookie to server next time , **and i want add a custom filter to verify url parameter value with cookie from client  . when cookie value is not valid with url parameter value, redirect to login page.**

I have tried to extend **AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter** , but i don't know how to add filter in http-sercurity （add fileter before or after ?）,
 and how to redirect to login page(because i want redirect to original page after success login).

**Update:**
 I can get cookie from controller ,redirect to login page when cookie is not valid . But it will not redirect to original page after success login ,because 
 i use spring security to login and **request cache** in **SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler** is null , so i want add filter to do this in spring security

Comment: Headers, Cookies and Parameters with REST-assured - https://www.baeldung.com/rest-assured-header-cookie-parameter

Comment: yeah , i know what you mean , i can get cookie from controller ,redirect to login page when cookie is not valid . But it will not redirect to original page because request cache is null , so i want do this in spring security

Comment: @Buffer You don't need to implement `AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter`. It is enough to implement `Filter` or `GenericFilter`. To redirect your request, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2047122/requestdispatcher-forward-vs-httpservletresponse-sendredirect

Comment: @dur But i don't know  how to add filter in http-sercurity （add filter before or after which filter）.  I have already debug  whole process flow and i don't know when spring security begin to deal with cookie about whether it need to be authenticated.

Comment: @Buffer Spring Security doesn't deal with cookie. The session cookie is part of the server.